# ¿Cómo pasar a producción varios JS con Webpack?

Tags: nodejs, backend, webpack, frontend

Muy buenas tardes, Estoy usando webpack, Mi pregunta es, Tengo un archivo index.js que es donde **importo la app con express del archivo app.js**, pero ahí puse igual la lógica del Frontend de la pagina y me da error
Pensé en separarlos en 2 archivos front y back(login.js e index.js) pero el webpack agarra el index.js por defecto, **¿Cómo le digo que agarre el de la lógica del front tambien?** y aunque lo agarre, los HTML por defecto se ligan al bundle que genera el webpack del index.js en la carpeta de producción(build), se ligarían al de la app con express que les mencione, **¿Cómo paso la lógica front a producción y la ligo a los HTML?**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Hay que configurar el entry con variables indicandoles la url de cada archivo js que quieras usar

```
    entry: {
    login: './src/public/scripts/index.js',
    register: './src/public/scripts/register.js',
    index_traveler: './src/public/scripts/index.traveler.js',
},
```

Y mas adelante en el HTMLWebpackPlugin le indicas con la propiedad **chunks** cual archivo js usará (de los que ya indicaste previamente)

```
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/public/views/index.html'),
        chunks: ['login'],
        minify: false, 
    }),
```

Esto lo repites para cada html